# Expanding network to outbuilding

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm not the most tech savvy so would appreciate some help
I have connected a  router to a cable wireless modem which works fine. I have from the wireless cable modem ethernet port run a cable down to an outbuildings and connected a router that's not configured for the network so is not showing a broadband signal.
How do I configure that router and how do i stop it interfering with my network as it will be a tenant using the WiFi and I don't want any complication of signal but for them to have there own independent secure wireless signal. Cable works fine, its genesis modem to an old bt home hub router. I have my own house router tp-link also coming out of ethernet port of cable modem. That works fine
Thanks

Comment: How long is the cable? Have you tested the cable? How is the cable routed?

Comment: Cables fine, there is another router connected from old tenant, but of course don't know password to access it . So putting in new router.

Comment: Ethernet port of modem into ethernet plotting new router

Comment: Is the cable showing a link light when plugged in? Can you provide the make and model numbers of both devices? It may just be that both are on the classic network default settings which would be conflicting. **Please add these details to the question and not the comments section.**